# How can I get tasks in TFS to retain owner after completion?

Tags: tfs

Right now my stories in TFS are being completed, but each time I drag to "Done" the task -- and even stories -- are losing my name on them.

This really gets complicated during scrum, when we're tracking yesterday's activity...

Comment: Which process template are you using? Agile? Scrum?

Comment: Also, you could change your query to use "Assigned To Was Ever @Me"

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am using Agile with daily scrums....

Comment: That may or may not answer my question. There are three built-in process templates in TFS 2013: Scrum, Agile, and CMMI. Which of those are you using? Also, which version of TFS?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ahhh... I am not sure.  I am not an admin... But we do have Kanban boards setup, and Iterations, and backlog... nots ure if those are all in each of the 3 templates or not...?

Comment: Yeah, those are in all three templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have so many items that you can't remember which ones for the story that you were working on were yours then you are doing it wrong.

You can change the work item type to stop this happening. Use witadmin to export the work item and then in the Workflow section remove the call to empty the Assigned To field. Then import it.

I would recommend that you test this on another non-production TFS server incase you ness it up.

Comment: You can also use the Process Template Editor Powertool.

Comment: "If you have so many items that you can't remember which ones for the story that you were working on were yours then you are doing it wrong." Actually, we have so many people on the project that when one day goes by, we have 10-15 new "done" items in TFS, up in the right hand corner, under "unassigned" and this becomes excruciatingly un-useful. So it's not that we can't remember who did what; it's that no one else can tell just by looking.

Comment: @BrooksHanes I would then suggest that you break your big team into smaller cross functional teams of 6+-3. You can still have your big Product Management team for overall priory and then assign work to the satellite Team. You then get both macro view for management and micro view for execution. Example: http://nakedalm.com/modelling-teams-in-team-foundation-server-2013/